# Mismatch between apple developer documentation and functions in swift playgrounds

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

In the apple developer documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417770-applyimpulse), the `applyImpluse` function from `SpriteKit` seems to have two parameters: `impulse:` and `duration:`. However, when I go into Swift Playgrounds and create a playground, after importing SpriteKit I seem to get this function in my auto complete: `dot.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector)` (where dot is a `SKShapeNode`).

Now, If you noticed, the function only takes one parameter, which is impulse, but not duration. Trying to insert a `duration:` parameter raises errors, and playgrounds, tries to suggest different function with a `at:` parameter. The same thing happens with applyForce.

This also happens if dot is a `SKSpriteNode`.

I am confused, as this shouldn't happen. Have I misread the docs, or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look on the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417770-applyimpulse) that you sent you can notice that method is `class function`. And you are calling that method on the instance instead of class.

```
class SomeClass {
    class func someTypeMethod() {
        // type method implementation goes here
    }
}
SomeClass.someTypeMethod()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! If you dont mind, could you also tell me how I can call these class functions to dot?

Comment: I'm not sure but `SKShapeNode` has method `runAction:` so I would create the action using `SKAction.applyImpulse(...)` and call that method on your `SKShapeNode` object with created action as a param.